# Flowplayer bind onFinish event

Tags: events, video, flowplayer

I have flowplayer setup on a landing page I'm building and it works fine and all but I can't get to fire an event when the clip finishes. Here's the code I'm using, I may be implementing it wrong but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
$("#teaser_player").flowplayer({
    playlist: [
                [
                    { mp4:  "videos/video1.mp4" },
                    { webm: "videos/video1.webm" },
                    { ogg:  "videos/video1.ogv" }
                ]
            ],
            clip:  {
                autoPlay: false,
                autoBuffering: true,
            },
            preload: true,
            fullscreen: false
        });

var elem = document.getElementById("teaser_player");
api = flowplayer(elem);

$("#puzzle4_video").fadeIn(500, function(){
api.play();
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well wouldn't you know it, I figured it out right after posting this.

Here's what I did

```
api.bind("finish", function(e, api) {
    alert("Alert");
});
```

Good Day